# How(is it possible) to add a dependency to my android library(aar)?

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, aar

I'm working on an android library project, that depends on exoplayer.
This library going to be distributed manually as an aar (not through Maven repositories).
For test purposes, I create a project and add aar as a new module as described in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library).

My problem that there is no exoplayer library as a dependency in a project and error occurred.

I tried to add exoplayer in aar using api and implementation:

```
api ("com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.4") {
    transitive = true
}
```

I added a new module to a project(File->new->New Module->import jar/aar), checked that there is included module in settings.gradle    `include ':app', ':my_module'`, added dependecy in app's gradle file     `implementation project(':my_module')`.

Now, I can use classes defined in my library, but a crash occurred when library trying to use exoplayer.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player$DefaultEventListener"
```

**Bad solution:**
I can ask users of my library manually add exoplayer as a dependency to there app, but I see a lot of problems with this approach.`implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.4"`

**My thought:**
It should be possible just to add a dependency to a library. I did some research and there are a lot of contradictions in answers. Someone said that jars should be shipped inside, someone said that there is a problem with dependencies when library added not through maven repository.

**Question:** How to add a dependency to my android library? Where I have a lack of knowledge to understand what's wrong?
Any ideas, thoughts, references are appreciated.

p.s.

- android studio v3.5
- com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0

Comment: What you can do is distribute it as a local maven repository. The .aar together with a pom.xml containing the dependencies is packed in a directory. In the project gradle file, this directory is referenced as a repo and the module gradle file, it's referenced as any other dependency. Would that be an option?

Comment: @Michiel I don't have experience in local maven repositories and it's pitfalls. I'll try to look forward to this direction and get back here later. Thanks.